# ERROR TypeError: "_co.pagination is undefined" and ERROR CONTEXT is being thrown with NGX-Bootstrap Pagination

Tags: angular, pagination

I am trying to use NGX Bootstrap Pagination to bring into my angular project. When I run the application the console displays this error.

I know the back end is working appropriately since I did testing with PostMan. The issue happens as soon as I add the pagination into the HTML. Specifically when i try to tie values like [totalItems]="pagination.totalItems". As soon as I add these values, the page breaks and the error is thrown.

The member-list component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UserService } from '../../_services/user.service';
import { AlertifyService } from '../../_services/alertify.service';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Pagination, PaginatedResult } from 'src/app/_models/pagination';
import { User } from 'src/app/_models/user';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-member-list',
  templateUrl: './member-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./member-list.component.css']
})
export class MemberListComponent implements OnInit {
  users: User[];
  pagination: Pagination;

  constructor(private userService: UserService, private alertify: AlertifyService,
              private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.data.subscribe(data => {
      this.users = data['users'].result;
      this.pagination = data['users'].pagination;
    });
  }

  pageChanged(event: any): void {
    this.pagination.currentPage = event.page;
  }
}
```

Member list html

```
<div class="container mt-5">
<div class="row">
  <div *ngFor="let user of users" class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-6">
    <app-member-card [user]="user"></app-member-card>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
<pagination
    [boundaryLinks]="true"
    [totalItems]="pagination.totalItems"
    [(ngModel)]="pagination.currentPage"
    [itemsPerPage]="pagination.itemsPerPage"
    (pageChanged)="pageChanged($event)"
  previousText="&lsaquo;" nextText="&rsaquo;" firstText="&laquo;" lastText="&raquo;">

</pagination>
</div>
```

App module

```
import { BrowserModule, HAMMER_GESTURE_CONFIG, HammerGestureConfig } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { NgxGalleryModule } from 'ngx-gallery';
import { PaginationModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/pagination';
import { TabsModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/tabs';
import { ModalModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
import {BsDatepickerModule} from 'ngx-bootstrap/datepicker';
import {BsDropdownModule} from 'ngx-bootstrap/dropdown';
import {NgxPaginationModule} from 'ngx-pagination';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavComponent } from './nav/nav.component';
import { AuthService } from './_services/auth.service';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from './register/register.component';
import { ErrorInterceptorProvider } from './_services/error.interceptor';
import { ListsComponent } from './lists/lists.component';
import { MessagesComponent } from './messages/messages.component';
import { appRoutes } from './routes';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { MemberListComponent } from './members/member-list/member-list.component';
import { MemberCardComponent } from './members/member-card/member-card.component';
import { AlertifyService } from './_services/alertify.service';
import { AuthGuard } from './_guards/auth.guard';
import { UserService } from './_services/user.service';
import { MemberDetailComponent } from './members/member-detail/member-detail.component';
import { MemberDetailResolver } from './_resolvers/member-detail.resolver';
import { MemberListResolver } from './_resolvers/member-list.resolver';
import { JwtModule } from '@auth0/angular-jwt';
import { MemberEditComponent } from './members/member-edit/member-edit.component';
import { MemberEditResolver } from './_resolvers/member-edit.resolver';
import { PreventUnsavedChanges } from './_guards/prevent-unsaved-changes.guard';
import { PhotoEditorComponent } from './members/photo-editor/photo-editor.component';
import { FileUploadModule } from 'ng2-file-upload';


export function tokenGetter() {
   return localStorage.getItem('token');
}

export class CustomHammerConfig extends HammerGestureConfig {
   overrides = {
      pinch: {enable: false},
      rotate: {enable: false}
   };
}

@NgModule({
   declarations: [
      AppComponent,
      NavComponent,
      HomeComponent,
      RegisterComponent,
      MemberListComponent,
      ListsComponent,
      MessagesComponent,
      MemberCardComponent,
      MemberDetailComponent,
      MemberEditComponent,
      PhotoEditorComponent
   ],
   imports: [
      BrowserModule,
      BrowserAnimationsModule,
      CommonModule,
      HttpClientModule,
      FormsModule,
      ReactiveFormsModule,
      BrowserAnimationsModule,
      BsDropdownModule.forRoot(),
      TabsModule.forRoot(),
      BsDatepickerModule.forRoot(),
      PaginationModule.forRoot(),
      RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
      NgxGalleryModule,
      ModalModule.forRoot(),
      FileUploadModule,
      NgxPaginationModule,
      JwtModule.forRoot({
         config: {
            tokenGetter,
            whitelistedDomains: ['localhost:5000'],
            blacklistedRoutes: ['localhost:5000/api/auth']
         }
      })
   ],
   providers: [
      AuthService,
      ErrorInterceptorProvider,
      AlertifyService,
      AuthGuard,
      UserService,
      MemberDetailResolver,
      MemberListResolver,
      MemberEditResolver,
      PreventUnsavedChanges,
      { provide: HAMMER_GESTURE_CONFIG, useClass: CustomHammerConfig}
   ],
   bootstrap: [
      AppComponent
   ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Model for pagination

```
export interface Pagination {
    currentPage: number;
    itemsPerPage: number;
    totalItems: number;
    totalPages: number;
}

export class PaginatedResult<T> {
    result: T;
    pagination: Pagination;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

I added a console log to see what is happening.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.route.data.subscribe(data => {
      this.users = data['users'].result;
      console.log(this.users);
      this.p = data['users'].pagination;
      console.log(this.p);
     console.log(this.users);
    });
}
```

When I look at the console.log() it is saying that p (pagination) is undefined

Answer (score 0):

Probably because `pagination` is only assigned in `ngOnInit()`, but the component is trying to access it before

Try only rendering component once the variable has been initialised

```
<pagination *ngIf="pagination"
 ...
```

Comment: That helped to remove the error, but it is removing the pagination item at the bottom from the page.

Comment: Well, you wrote the answer to that yourself: `When I look at the console.log() it is saying that p (pagination) is undefined`. You need to correctly retrieve the pagination data

Comment: I know, im confused in how it is still undefined. i have it defined, but it is missing something i am not seeing.